# Simple C program is not storing the correct value of the input taken in the variable

Tags: c, input

Can anybody tell me where why the correct value of input is not being stored in this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num, sum=0;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    while(num!=0)
    {
        sum = sum+num;
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
    printf("Answerr = %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

> ```
> Enter the number: 2
> 0
> Sum = 10
> ```

Comment: You need to read *before* adding it to `sum`.  Right now, `num` is used uninitialized. `sum = sum+num; scanf("%d", &num);` -> `scanf("%d", &num);sum = sum+num;`

Comment: You haven't initialised `num`. That is why you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: also, you're not checking the return value of [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot know what exactly this part will do :

```
while (num != 0)
{
    sum = sum + num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
}
```

because `num` is not initialized, so you are adding to `sum` a value which you do not know. Change it to :

```
while(num != 0)
{
    scanf("%d", &num);
    sum = sum + num;
}
```

so that `num` has a value when you add it, and also initialize `num` to something different than `0`, for example :

```
int num = 2;
```

so that your `while` loop is executed at least one (in other words, so that you get the chance to read `num`).

---

A better approach would be to use a [do-while](/questions/tagged/do-while) loop like this :

```
int num = 0;
do
{
    scanf("%d", &num);
    sum = sum + num;
}while (num != 0);
```

so as to be sure that your loop will be executed at least once. Even with this approach you should still initialize `num` *in case `scanf` fails* (and therefore `num` does not get a value).

In order to check the return value of `scanf`, use this piece of code :

```
if ( scanf("%d", &num) == 1)
    sum = sum + num;
```

Comment: a `do/while` is always the best solution when you want to enter at least once in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Better do:

```
num= 0;
do
{
    scanf("%d", &num);
    sum = sum+num;
} while(num!=0);
```

Note the initialization of `num` is still needed as `scanf` could fail which would not affect `num`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 0, sum = 0;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    do
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &num);
        sum = sum + num;
    } while (num != 0);

    printf("Answer = %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I replaced the `while`loop with a `do while` one. You've to initialize `sum`, otherwise you'll work with an undefined value in your first run ( if working with a `while` loop).

Answer (score 0):

The variable `num` was not initialized. As result the loop has undefined behavior. Also you should check whether the input was valid before adding values.  Take into account that neither declaration from the header `<stdlib.h>` is used. So you may remove the header.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        int num;

        printf( "Enter number (0 - exit): " );

        if ( scanf( "%d", &num) != 1 || num == 0 ) break;

        sum += num;
    }

    printf( "\nAnswer = %lld\n", sum );

    return 0;
}
```

Or you could place the prompt before the loop as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    printf( "Enter numbers (0 - exit): " );

    while ( 1 )
    {
        int num;

        if ( scanf( "%d", &num) != 1 || num == 0 ) break;

        sum += num;
    }

    printf( "\nAnswer = %lld\n", sum );

    return 0;
}
```

And according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 0):

you are adding value of num before reading it
do like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num, sum=0;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    do{
        scanf("%d", &num);
         sum = sum+num;

    }
    while(num!=0);

    printf("Answerr = %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `num` needs to be initialized.